# Conditionally render @ResourceDependency in JSF component

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, components

I am currently developing a new JSF component library, based on jQuery. I use the `@ResourceDependency` in the component's renderer to define jQuery as a dependency. Everything works fine up to the time when I am creating the showcase, which uses also Primefaces.
The problem now is, that also PrimeFaces declares jQuery as dependency, so now two jQuery.js files get rendered in the page's head.

Besides the fact that it makes no sense to transfer the same js file (in this case it is really the same version), also on the client side this causes problems as the jQuery plugins only exist in the jQuery/$ instance that was loaded right before the plugins were initialized, but not in the jQuery-Instance that was instantiated/loaded after the PrimeFaces or my libraries .js file was loaded.

So I need a way to only load jQuery if it was not already included by another library / PrimeFaces. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think this is next to impossible. And if you use jquery in a [noconflict mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), you might not have any problem besides the duplicate loading (which will be cached if done correctly). Write your own head renderer wil also result in problems where the existing head renderers will fail. One thing you *can* do is to extend PrimeFaces like PrimeFaces Extensions does and use more of the PF basics/utils etc. I've done this for two components and it works fine, but yes, you are dependend on PF then